# Applet Upload Error

Tags: java, php, forms, security, applet

I want to upload some files from client pc to my web server and I am using following code in Java applet I have also signed applet successfully and it prompt for Trust the applet see code here, but it does not uploads the file

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class UploaderExample extends Applet
{
private static final String Boundary = "--7d021a37605f0";

public void upload(URL url, List<File> files) throws Exception
{
    HttpURLConnection theUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    theUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    theUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    theUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    theUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);

    theUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="
            + Boundary);

    DataOutputStream httpOut = new DataOutputStream(theUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        File f = files.get(i);
        String str = "--" + Boundary + "\r\n"
                   + "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"file" + i + "\"; filename=\"" + f.getName() + "\"\r\n"
                   + "Content-Type: image/png\r\n"
                   + "\r\n";

        httpOut.write(str.getBytes());

        FileInputStream uploadFileReader = new FileInputStream(f);
        int numBytesToRead = 1024;
        int availableBytesToRead;
        while ((availableBytesToRead = uploadFileReader.available()) > 0)
        {
            byte[] bufferBytesRead;
            bufferBytesRead = availableBytesToRead >= numBytesToRead ? new byte[numBytesToRead]
                    : new byte[availableBytesToRead];
            uploadFileReader.read(bufferBytesRead);
            httpOut.write(bufferBytesRead);
            httpOut.flush();
        }
        httpOut.write(("--" + Boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());

    }

    httpOut.write(("--" + Boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());

    httpOut.flush();
    httpOut.close();

    // read & parse the response
    InputStream is = theUrlConnection.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] respBuffer = new byte[4096];
    while (is.read(respBuffer) >= 0)
    {
        response.append(new String(respBuffer).trim());
    }
    is.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
    list.add(new File("C:\\square.png"));
    list.add(new File("C:\\narrow.png"));
    UploaderExample uploader = new UploaderExample();
    uploader.upload(new URL("http://localhost/test2/upload.php"), list);
 }

}
```

Console Output is

```
security: User has granted the priviledges to the code for this session only
security: Adding certificate in Deployment session certificate store
security: Added certificate in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate hasnt been expired, no need to check timestamping info
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment session certificate store
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate hasnt been expired, no need to check timestamping info
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment session certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 121613 us,       pluginInit dt 29241825 us, TotalTime: 29363438 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Comment: Is the applet called by JS?  What is the HTML?  What is the console output?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Console Output is shown in edited version of this question also html is just by including tag of applet

Comment: @AndrewThompson You didnot identified the error?

Comment: What code calls `upload(..)`?